# Consistency of the minimizer of the convex loss

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convex-analysis, asymptotics

This is an exercise from the Stanford Stat 300B course, which I am auditing and don't have the solutions for. It is taken from the following source (Q2.6): https://web.stanford.edu/class/stats300b/Exercises/all-exercises.pdf. I have been stuck on the question for quite a while and think that I am missing some important part.

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a measurable space and $X_i \sim P$ be i.i.d, where $P$ is a probability distribution on $\mathcal{X}$. Let $\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be an open set and let $l :\Theta \times \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$ be a loss function. Define the risk functional $R(\theta) := E_P [l(\theta, X)]$, which is the expected loss of a vector $\theta$. Let $ \theta^* := \arg \min_{\theta\in\Theta} R(\theta)$. Define the empirical risk functional as $\hat{R}_n := \frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n l(\theta, X_i)$. Let $ \hat{\theta}_n := \arg \min_{\theta\in\Theta} \hat{R}_n(\theta)$.

We also have the following assumptions:

1. $\theta \to l(\theta, x)$ is convex
2. $\nabla^2 R(\theta^*) \succ 0$ i.e. the Hessian of the risk is positive definite at $\theta^*$
3. $\theta^* \in \text{interior of }\Theta$
4. There is a function $H : X → R^+$ such that $E[H^2(X)] < \infty$ and the Hessian $\nabla^2l(\theta, x)$ is $H(x)$-Lipschitz in $\theta$, that is, $$|| \nabla^2l(\theta, x) - \nabla^2l(\theta', x)||_{op} \leq H(x)||\theta - \theta'||~~\forall \theta,\theta'\in\Theta$$
5. Assume that gradients and Hessians can be passed through all expectations and integrals and as many moments of $\nabla l$ as you need.
6. Also assume the following theorem holds true. If $f$ is convex and satisfies $\nabla^2 f(x) 
    - \lambda I\succ 0$ for all $x$ such that $||x - x_0|| \leq c$, then: $$ f(x) \geq f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0)(x - x_0) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\min(||x-x_0||^2, c||x-x_0||)$$

Need to show that under these assumptions: $\hat{\theta}_n \to \theta^*$ in probability.

I feel hopelessly overwhelmed by all the details. I am not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: That is an absolutely huge set of conditions. Probably we must try to understand how to see why each condition is required in the first place, then we can put them together? I will see if I can look at worked examples of similar questions and try to help you.

Comment: I think the basic idea should be pretty clear: We need to apply an appropriate [concentration inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality), the side conditions should allow us to get some bound on the variance of $\hat\theta_N$

Answer (score 3):

Careful: this proof requires one additionnal technical assumption, that is, that for any $\theta$, $\nabla^2 l(\theta,X)$ be $L^1$ (or, equivalently given condition 4, that $\nabla^2 l(\theta^*,X)$ be $L^1$).

Here's how the proof roughly goes (there's a slight technicality, but this is how the proof works if $\Theta$ is bounded): we show (part two) that there exists some integer $N_0$ such that for any $\theta$ and any $n \geq N_0$, with high probability, the inequality $|\hat{R_n}(\theta)-R(\theta)| \leq \epsilon$ holds.

Thus, with high probability, we have $R(\hat{\theta_n})\leq \hat{R_n}(\hat{\theta_n})+\epsilon \leq \hat{R_n}(\theta^*) +\epsilon\leq R(\theta^*)+2\epsilon$.

Now, $R(\theta)$ is convex, and we know that its minimum is reached at $\theta$ in the interior of the domain, and we know that $R(\hat{\theta_n})$ is close to said minimum (with high probability), which will imply (part one) that $\hat{\theta_n}$ is close to $\theta^*$.

$ $

**First part: the convex analysis**

By assumption, $R(\theta)$ is a convex function, twice differentiable, with $\theta^*$ as a global minimum, and $\nabla^2 R(\theta^*)$ is positive definite. Let $\lambda > 0$ be its smallest eigenvalue.

Moreover, we have $\|\nabla^2 R(\theta)-\nabla^2R(\theta')\|_{op}\leq\mathbb{E}_{x \sim P}[\|\nabla^2 l(\theta,x)-\nabla^2 l(\theta',x)\|_{op}] \leq \mathbb{E}_x[H(x)\|\theta-\theta'\|] \leq C\|\theta-\theta'\|$, that is $\nabla^2 R$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $C$. Note that $C,\lambda$ are parameters of the problem.

Let $\theta \in \Theta$ (which we assume is convex), then consider $f(t)=R((1-t)\theta^*+t\theta)$. Then $f$ is $C^2$, convex, minimal at zero (thus increasing), $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0) \geq \lambda \|\theta-\theta^*\|^2$. We want to show that if $f(1)-f(0)$ is small, then so must be $\delta=\|\theta-\theta^*\|^2$.

Indeed, let $\tau = \lambda/C$ (up to choosing a larger $C$, we assume $\tau < 1$). For $t \leq 1$, $f''(t) \geq \delta(\lambda-Ct)$, so for $t \leq \tau$, $f'(t)\geq \delta\lambda t-\delta Ct^2/2$ and thus $f(t)-f(0) \geq \delta \lambda t^2/2-\delta C t^3/6$. In particular $f(1)-f(0) \geq f(\tau)-f(0) \geq \frac{1}{6}\delta \tau^2 (3\lambda-\tau C)=\frac{\delta \tau^2 \lambda}{3}$.

Thus, we have, for any $\theta \in \Theta$, $$\|\theta-\theta^*\|^2 \leq \frac{3}{\tau^2 \lambda}(R(\theta)-R(\theta^*)).$$

$ $

**Second part: the probability**

We want to find a uniform bound on $\theta \in \Theta$ on the probability that $|\hat{R_n}(\theta)-R(\theta)|\geq \epsilon$. It turns out that the estimate we really can use (in absence of a $L^2$ moment bound for $l$ which is uniform in $\theta$) requires using derivatives, and thus we'll need to set a positive bound $B>0$ and consider only the $\theta$ such that $\|\theta-\theta^*\| \leq B$.

Now, by Taylor, if $\theta_t=(1-t)\theta^*+t\theta$, $$\hat{R_n}(\theta)-R(\theta) = \hat{R_n}(\theta^*)-R(\theta^*)+\nabla (\hat{R_n}-R)(\theta^*)\cdot (\theta-\theta^*) + \frac{1}{2}(\theta-\theta^*)^T\times \nabla^2(\hat{R_n}-R)(\theta^*)\times (\theta-\theta^*) + \int_0^1{(1-t)(\theta-\theta^*)^T \times (\nabla^2(\hat{R_n}-R)(\theta_t)-\nabla^2(\hat{R_n}-R)(\theta^*)) \times (\theta-\theta^*)\,dt}$$.

Let $V(X) = l(\theta^*,X)$, $G(X)=\nabla l(\theta^*,X)$, $L(X)=\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 l(\theta^*,X)$. Finally, define $W^{\theta}(X) = \int_0^1{(1-t)(\nabla^2 l(\theta_t,X)-\nabla^2 l(\theta^*,X))\,dt}$.

By the weak law of large numbers, we know that there is a $N=N^0_{\epsilon}(\theta^*,B)$ such that for all $n \geq N$:

1. $P\left(|\hat{V}_n-\mathbb{E}[V]| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{8}$.
2. $P\left(\|\hat{G}_n-\mathbb{E}[G]\| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8(B+1)}\right) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{8}$.
3. $P\left(\|\hat{L}_n-\mathbb{E}[L]\|_{op} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8(B+1)^2}\right) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{8}$.

Finally, note that $$\mathbb{E}[\|W^{\theta}\|^2_{op}] \leq \int_0^1{(1-t)^2\mathbb{E}[\|\nabla^2 l(\theta_t,X)-\nabla^2 l(\theta^*,X)\|_{op}^2]\,dt} \leq \int_0^1{(1-t)^2\mathbb{E}[H^2]\|\theta_t-\theta^*\|^2\,dt} = \|\theta-\theta^*\|^2\mathbb{E}[H^2] \int_0^1{(1-t)^2t^2\,dt} \leq C'B^2$$ for some $C' > 0$.

Thus, reasoning coordinate-wise, and recalling that the variance of a $L^2$ random variable $A$ is at most $\mathbb{E}[A^2]$, we have $P\left(\|(\hat{W^{\theta}})_n-\mathbb{E}[W^{\theta}]\|^2 \geq \frac{\epsilon^2}{64(B+1)^4}\right) \leq \frac{64C'B^2(B+1)^4}{n\epsilon^2}$.

So if $n$ is large enough, with probability at least $1-\epsilon/8$ that $|(\theta-\theta^*)^T \times ((\hat{W^{\theta}})_n - \mathbb{E}[W^{\theta}]) \times (\theta-\theta^*)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{8}$.

It follows from this that with for $n \geq N_{\epsilon}(\theta^*,B)$, for any $\theta \in \Theta$ at distance at most $B$ of $\theta^*$, with probability at least $1-\epsilon/2$, $|\hat{R}_n(\theta)-R(\theta)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

$ $

**Part three: the complete proof**

Fix $B > \sqrt{\frac{3}{\tau^2 \lambda}}$, some $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and take $n \geq N_{\epsilon}(\theta^*,B)$.

Now choose $\theta$ on the line segment linking $\hat{\theta_n}$ to $\theta^*$ and at distance at most $B$ of $\theta^*$.

Then with probability $1-\epsilon$, the inequalities $\hat{R_n}(\theta^*) \leq R(\theta^*)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\hat{R_n}(\theta) \geq R(\theta)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ both hold.

Now, $t \in [0,1] \longmapsto \hat{R_n}((1-t)\theta^*+t\hat{\theta_n})$ is convex, minimal at $t=1$, and thus is nonincreasing, and $\hat{R_n}(\theta)$ is some $f(t)$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$, which implies that $\hat{R_n}(\theta) \leq \hat{R_n}(\theta^*)$.

Therefore, with probability $1-\epsilon$ at least, $R(\theta) \leq \hat{R_n}(\theta) +\frac{\epsilon}{2} \leq \hat{R_n}(\theta^*)+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \leq R(\theta^*)+\epsilon$.

So by part one, for any $\theta \in [\theta^*,\hat{\theta_n}]$ with distance at most $B$ from $\theta^*$, with probability at least $1-\epsilon$, $\|\theta-\theta^*\|^2 \leq \frac{3\epsilon}{\tau^2 \lambda}$. In particular, if we choose the farthest possible $\theta$ from $\theta^*$, (still with probability at least $1-\epsilon$), the inequality $\min(B,\|\hat{\theta_n}-\theta^*\|) \leq \sqrt{\frac{3\epsilon}{\tau^2\lambda}}$ holds. By the definition of $B$, it follows that with probability $1-\epsilon$ at least, $\|\theta^*-\hat{\theta_n}\| \leq \sqrt{\frac{3\epsilon}{\tau^2\lambda}}$, which concludes.

Comment: I think this might work as answer. But although probably correct, your solution does nt seem to use the provided hint (#6). It also contains some typos and is a little hard to follow.

Comment: I use my own, convex-analytical version of 6. That’s my “part one”. I’ve tried to summarize the approach before “part one”. Not sure where it’s unclear, I’ll gladly explain the parts you have questions about.